ADO xls connection issue
i am using ADO xls integration. Xls which was created by open in xls option, in that xls somehow i deleted the query which available in row 1, later i readded that query but now  my connection to ADO not working i.e. teams tab is completed greyed out. How i can fix this connection. i don't want to create new sheet
In Data tab- existing connection, i tried correcting connection name and command text in properties, it have deleted string added now with existing connection name but still connection is not working
